# Consultas en tiempo real

Tags: java, mysql

Quiero hacer una consulta en tiempo real base de datos, para cada vez que se inserte un registro, me muestre el valor que acaba de registrar.

No soy muy conocedor de los métodos o funciones que se pueden utilizar java para hacer esta consulta, estoy utilizando el siguiente código para hacer la consulta cada cierto tiempo pero no se si esto a largo plazo con largas horas de ejecución pueda generar error.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.print(e);

            //Aquí tengo la consulta que me devuelve la suma de valores 
            totales registrados en una tabla de ventas
            i=1;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código no hace realmente algo útil dado que dentro del `try` solo pone a dormir al 
`Thread` 10 veces a intervalos de 1 segundo.

El siguiente ejemplo, levanta un thread en background para correr las consultas.
Se ejecuta en un loop infinito.
Y mientras, el `Thread` principal se blockea leyendo un valor de la consola.
Cuando el valor ingresado es `X` (enter), detiene el loop infinito (al momento de evaluar la condición del loop).

```
public class Main {

    private Thread queryThread;
    private boolean end = false;

    public static void main(String ...args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.start(args);
    }

    private void start(String ... args) {
        queryThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!end) {
                    try{
                        runQuery();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        });

        queryThread.start();

        while(!end) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter X to exit");
                int read = System.in.read();
                if (read == (int) 'X') {
                    System.out.println("Shutting down gracefully");
                    end = true;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void  runQuery() {
        // Aquí tengo la consulta que me devuelve la suma de valores 
        // totales registrados en una tabla de ventas
        System.out.println("Running query at " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }

}
```